# Python ctrl+c, excute function if early termination

Tags: python, python-2.7, interrupt-handling

I have a python script that creates a lot of temporary files. If the script terminates early because of a ctrl+c interrupt, I would like to quickly delete those files before the program is allowed to end.

What's the pythonic way handling this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the files in a `with` statement, if possible, or use a `try` statement with a `finally` block that closes the files. If you're using [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html), the files will automatically be destroyed when closed; otherwise, you may need to delete them yourself in the `finally` block.

Comment: Using the `try: finally:` syntax is particularly useful because if your program exits for a different reason than `KeyboardInterrupt` (say, an exception) you still get your temp. files deleted.

Comment: @JosephDunn: +1. And using `with` or `try: finally:` or `tempfile` instead of `try: except:` _also_ means you can scrap most of the manual cleanup that's probably already written for successful cases, making the code simpler.

Comment: By the way, `tempfile` makes everything incredibly easy under Unix, as long as you pick the right class… but on Windows, many cases are still a pain. (But still often a little less painful than trying to do it manually.)

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    main()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    cleanUp()
```

Answer (score 0):

Either catch and handle `KeyboardInterrupt`, or set an exit handler with [`atexit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html).

Also, [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html).